# Spark Dataframe order preservation .Does calling the save operation on orderBy dataframe preserves ordering

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I ran some test cases from a spark shell .  The statement that i executed were of the form .

read.orderBy($"p_int".asc ).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save(“file:///tmp/output.txt”)

The content in the output directory  seems to always be sorted. however I cannot  find any documentation in spark that even related to any guarantees provided by either the DataFrameWriter in terms of preserving partition order or  row order.

The question is  can i always expect the data in the target file to be sorted ?and please add any link to proper documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you coalesce to 1 partition before saving, the output will be sorted. Be careful thought, when reading back the .csv in spark, if in your spark config `spark.default.parallelism` is more than 1, ordering will be lost.